# Как конвертировать Long в int?

Tags: java, hql

```java
    @Override
    public int getCountItem(Map<String, Object> params) {
        return entityManager.createQuery("""
                                SELECT CAST(COUNT(t) as int) FROM Task t WHERE t.user.id = :userId"""
                          , Integer.class)
                .setParameter("userId", params.get("userId"))
                .getSingleResult();
```

При получении количества (`count`) Idea всегда ругается, как исправить?
Данный код работает отлично, но ругань со стороны Idea смущает.
Unboxing не срабатывает, приходится писать костыли `(CAST(COUNT(x) as int))` - но уверен, есть решение лучше.

Comment: А почему возникла  мысль что  проблема  с java?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасло вот такое решение: преобразование к Lobg, с последующим извлечением int

Answer (score 0):

```
Long x = 100L;
int y = x.intValue();
```

Или

```
Math.toIntExact(value);
```